# open submenus on click Jquery and still be able to click submenu li links

Tags: jquery, click, slidetoggle, submenu, slideup

This works to open my submenus, but I can't click on any pages in the submenus, because when an `li` is clicked it closes the `ul` without opening the page from the submenu... thoughts?

```
$('.menu').find('> li').click(function() {
    $('.menu > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: By removing this code chunk....  $('.menu > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp(); ... it will keep the submenu open, but can't click any submenu li links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with event.stopImmediatePropagation()

```
$('.menu').find('> li').click(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('.menu > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp(); //
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400); //
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: removed second line and changed false to true in the last line.

```
$('.menu').find('> li').click(function() {
$(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
return true;
});
```